# border-radius with gradient don't work in IE

Tags: wordpress, linear-gradients

[image]I tried to use border radius with linear gradients in IE-9, but it's not working together. I use specail filter for IE. Without gradient its working.  I spent much time but could't understand the reason. `button.new {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#00BBD6, #EBFFFF);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#00BBD6), to(#EBFFFF));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00BBD6', endColorstr='#EBFFFF');
    padding: 3px 7px;
    color: #333;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
<form action="">
    <p><button class="new">Новая кнопка</button></p>
  </form>`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gHQ58/)
You can see working example [here](http://ep.pusku.com/) I have problem also this menu and red button but i use example above to keep my code short.  I also tried to use CSS3pie for Wordpress to make my css3 working in IE 7-8 with [special code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Working_with_PIE_in_WordPress_for_older_IE_versions) for Word Press function php but it doesn't work too. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
background: rgb(0,187,214); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,187,214,1) 0%, rgba(235,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,187,214,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(235,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,187,214,1) 0%,rgba(235,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,187,214,1) 0%,rgba(235,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,187,214,1) 0%,rgba(235,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,187,214,1) 0%,rgba(235,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00bbd6', endColorstr='#ebffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

and for IE9 don't forget to add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, and add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

For rounded corners in IE9 you can add this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: THank you for answer! I use code to override IE in the header.php and put your css in my class. But button still show the square corners of colors. What extra step i can do to solve problem? Maybe the problem with my browser and in your browser it looks propely. Can you check?

Comment: this doesn't really solve the issue,  the override takes the gradient off of the button,  which then has rounded corners,  but the newer IE browsers dont use the filter css property to make gradients...  Generally speaking , you can't have round corners AND a gradient background in IE 9 without using an image.